# Failing to import new PKCS12 certificate into Evolution Mail

Tags: encryption, security, email, mint, signature

my PKCS12 certificate from my workplace institution expires in a few days. I already got a new one. Yet, I'm failing to import it into Evolution mail. When selecting Edit > Preferences > Certificates > Import, I can select the certificate.p12 file. I am asked to give my password but afterwards, nothing happens, only my old two certificates are listed.

For debugging purposes I started the evolution process from bash, did the exact same thing and this resulted in the following output:

```
importing pkcs12 from '/path/to/certificate.p12'
nickname_collision
PKCS12: NSS error: -8099 (Unable to import.  Error attempting to import private key.)
```

I then deleted the two older certificates from the list. Yet, the error still remains. Has anyone an idea?

Kind regards

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; and have used an off-topic distribution tag; what are you running & why did you use your tags?

Comment: I used the tag "mint" as it was displayed to me that this concerns questions specifically to Linux Mint. Sorry if that was wrong usage. I'm running Linux Mint 21.2 on a 5.15.0-84-generic kernel version.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: Don't forget Linux Mint has an additional layer of software that Ubuntu does **not** include (the runtime *adjustments* that allow them to use *foreign* Ubuntu packages). Ubuntu upgrades make no allowance for them, which means some *adjustments* need tweaking after security patches flow through from Ubuntu - these are usually evident on screen; but you're off-topic asking about those here; as Ubuntu & *flavors* all have write access to Ubuntu repositories, thus they don't use adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll check out a Mint forum.