# Cannot successfully import new PKCS12 certificate into Evolution Mail

Tags: email, evolution, certificates

Similar to this one,

[Failing to import new PKCS12 certificate into Evolution Mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487146/failing-to-import-new-pkcs12-certificate-into-evolution-mail)

but i'm on ubuntu 20.04 with evolution client version 3.36.5-0ubuntu1  and i get a different error when running evolution from commandline.

after running on commandline, to be clear i'm going to preferences > certificates > import > select

```
> evolution
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.

(evolution-alarm-notify:509623): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 15:19:58.145: Your application did not unregister from D-Bus before destruction. Consider using g_application_run().


** (evolution:509614): CRITICAL **: 15:20:02.948: Cannot register URI scheme evo-file more than once

** (evolution:509614): CRITICAL **: 15:20:02.948: Cannot register URI scheme gtk-stock more than once
importing pkcs12 from '....myfile.p12'
handle_error (7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I posted, i found the answer.

For me, the issue was the p12 cert had a password needed to install it, and i was given the wrong password.

Unfortunate that the app doesn't give me a clear error that the password was not accepted, but there you go internet